# Kernel of an algebra map and module of Kahler Differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $f:A\rightarrow k$ an algebra map with kernel $I$.

I'd like to prove that $\Omega_A\otimes_f k $ is canonically isomorphic to $I/I^2$.

This is from W.C.Waterhouse Intro to Aff. Group Schemes pag 85 (d).
I can get that given a $k$-linear derivation $D$ from a $A$ to some $k$-algebra $N$ upon which $A$ acts by $f$, $D$ must vanish on $I^2$ and so must factorize along the projection $p:A\rightarrow A/I^2$, but then what?

Related question: [Kahler differentials of a Hopf Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190724/differentials-of-hopf-algebras)

Comment: See Prop. II.8.7 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Yes, I see the proof in Hartshorne can be generalized to my case. Thank you.

Comment: @Youngsu In general $A$ is not a (semi)local $k$-algebra: I don't understand how one how use your hint.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos : For every element in $A$, you can define an element $i_a= a-fa$ , which belongs to $I$. So you get a linear map from $A$ to $I/I^2$

Comment: @Armandoj18eos The map $f$ is supported only at one point corresponding to the maximal ideal $I$. So, one may localize $A$ at $I$ assume that it is local. For this one may need $A$ to be of finite type. Was being of finite type your concern?

Comment: @Youngsu The result in Hartshorne is stated for a local ring, but in the more general case of my question you don't need to localize or the algebra $A$ to be of finite type. I think the proof goes as in Hartshorne by using the observation I wrote in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give here the sketch of my proof for the result:

We have from the exact sequence associated to the surjective map :→ the surjective morphism $\delta:I/I^2 \rightarrow Ω_⊗_ $ , which induces the injective morphism Der$_k(A,N) \rightarrow$ Hom$(I/I^2, N)$ for every $k$-algebra $N$ made into an $A$-algebra by $f$. If the induced morphism is also surjective for every $N$, our $\delta $ will be an isomorphism as we want.

So we just have to prove that Der$_k(A,N) \rightarrow$ Hom$(I/I^2, N)$ is surjective for every $N$:

For every element in , you can define an element $_=−\rho()$ (where $\rho$ is just the k-algebra structure of A), and $i_a$ belongs to  because $f\rho=id$; so you get a linear map $ \rightarrow/^2 $. 
By composing with this map you get a derivation $A\rightarrow I/I^2 \rightarrow N $ for every $k$-linear morphism in $Hom_k(I/I^2, N)$ , as we wanted

Answer (score 0):

Let $s:k\to A$ be the structure morphism of $A$ as $k$-algebra, I mean $s(\lambda)=\lambda\cdot1_A$ for any $\lambda\in K$, where $1_A$ is the (multiplicative) unit of $A$. By hypothesis, $f$ is a morphism of $k$-algebras; because
\begin{equation}
\forall\lambda\in k,\,f(s(\lambda))=f(\lambda\cdot1_A)=\lambda\cdot f(1_A)=\lambda\cdot1=\lambda
\end{equation}
that is $s$ is *section* of $f$, by [Stacks Project TAG 02HP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02HP) one has:
\begin{equation}
\Omega^1_{A/k}\otimes_fk\cong I_{\displaystyle/I^2}
\end{equation}
where $I=\ker f$.